# Apache Flink : Window Function on AllWindowed Stream - Combining Kafka Topics

Tags: json, merge, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am trying to combine two kafka topics using the a single kafka consumer on a list of topics, further convert the json string in the stream to POJO. Then, join them via keyBy ( On event time field ) and to merge them as a single fat json, I was planning to use a window stream and apply a window function on the window stream. The assumption is that Topic-A & Topic-B can be joined on Event Time and only one pair ( Topic A ( JSON ) , Topic B (JSON ) will be present with the same eventTime. Hence was planning to use a coutWindow(2) post keyBy on eventTime.

I have couple of questions for the same;

1. Is the approach fine for merging topics and creating a single JSON?
2. The window function on All Window stream doesnt seem to work fine; Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Code Snippet :

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

logger.info("Flink Stream Window Charger has started");

Properties properties = new Properties();

properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:1030");

properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "127.0.0.1:2181/service-kafka");

properties.setProperty("group.id", "group-0011");

properties.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");



List < String > names = new ArrayList < > ();



names.add("Topic-A");

names.add("Topic-B");



DataStream < String > stream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer08 < > (names, new SimpleStringSchema(), properties));

DataStream < TopicPojo > pojo = stream.map(new Deserializer()).keyBy((eventTime) -> TopicPojo.getEventTime());

List < String > where = new ArrayList < String > ();

AllWindowedStream < String, GlobalWindow > data_window = pojo.flatMap(new Tokenizer()).countWindowAll(2);

DataStream < String > data_charging = data_window.apply(new MyWindowFunction());

data_charging.addSink(new SinkFunction < String > () {



public void invoke(String value) throws Exception {



  // Yet to be implemented - Merge two POJO into one 

 }

});



try

{

 env.execute();

} catch (Exception e)

{

 return;

}

}

}

class Tokenizer implements FlatMapFunction < TopicPojo, String > {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1 L;

 @Override

 public void flatMap(TopicPojo value, Collector < String > out) throws Exception {

  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  out.collect(mapper.writeValueAsString(value));

 }

}

class MyWindowFunction implements WindowFunction < TopicPojo, String, String, GlobalWindow > {

 @Override

 public void apply(String key, GlobalWindow window, Iterable < TopicPojo > arg2, Collector < String > out)

 throws Exception {

  int count = 0;

  for (TopicPojo in : arg2) {

   count++;

  }

  // Test Result - TO be modified

  out.collect("Window: " + window + "count: " + count);



 }

}

class Deserializer implements MapFunction < String, TopicPojo > {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1 L;

 @Override

 public TopicPojo map(String value) throws IOException {

  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  TopicPojo obj = null;

  try {



   System.out.println(value);



   obj = mapper.readValue(value, TopicPojo.class);



  } catch (JsonParseException e) {



   // TODO Auto-generated catch block



   throw new IOException("Failed to deserialize JSON object.");



  } catch (JsonMappingException e) {



   // TODO Auto-generated catch block



   throw new IOException("Failed to deserialize JSON object.");

  } catch (IOException e) {



   // TODO Auto-generated catch block



   throw new IOException("Failed to deserialize JSON object.");

  }

  return obj;

 }

}
```

I am getting -

> The method apply(AllWindowFunction) in the type AllWindowedStream is not applicable for the arguments (MyWindowFunction) error.

Answer (score 2):

An AllWindowedStream is a non-keyed stream, and so the apply method for AllWindowedStreams doesn't have a key parameter. Since you are windowing a keyed stream, your data_window should be a KeyedStream.